# Can't increment the index of another loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I want to add the contents of a string that matches with a particular string to a list, but I have a problem. If I have more than a string, for example I have the string `"b c d"` as well as the string `"e"`, assuming that a word in `sys.argv` can be part only of a string, how can I jump from the control made for `"b c d"` directly to the control for `"e"`?

```
begin=1
length=len(sys.argv)
frase="b c d"
def funz(a,b):              #funz che torna una stringa    
    s=""
    for arg in sys.argv[a:b]:
        #print arg
        s+=arg+" "
    x=list(s)               #to delete the last whitespace
    x[len(x)-1]=""
    s="".join(x)
    print s
    return s
l=[]
def funz2(x):
    l.append(x)

for i in range(begin,length):
    for j in range(length,begin,-1):
        if funz(begin, length)==frase :
            #print length
            #print begin
            funz2(frase)
            length=length-1
            i=+length        #this doesn't increment i !
            break
            #print funz(begin,length) 
        else:
            #print length
            #print begin
            length=length-1
    begin=begin+1
    length=len(sys.argv)

print l
```

Comment: What? What is *"annidate"*? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can see what your question is about, but I am having a real hard time figuring out what problem you are trying to solve. There are probably easier ways to do what you want without nested loops and producing indices.

Comment: `funz` is the most complicated way to use `join` i ever have seen: `def funz(a,b): return " ".join(sys.argv[a:b])`

Comment: "annidate" seems to be Italian for nested.

Answer (score 2):

A Python `for` loop works with an iterable; `range()` produces a sequence of numbers that `for` loops over, and each iteration `i` is bound to next item in that sequence. `i` is not incremented by `for`, nor can you help that along in the loop.

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
i = begin - 1
while i < length:
    i += 1

    # rest of your loop
```

Now `i` *is* incremented as part of the loop, and you can increment it some more.

You already seem to know about `str.join()` but you missed an opportunity to use it for `funz`; the whole function could be replaced with:

```
def funz(a, b):
    return ' '.join(sys.argv[a:b])
```

which could just as well be inlined into your loops to avoid confusion. The same goes for `funz2`, which only serves to manipulate a global.